# I can't access some IPv6 websites

Tags: networking, ipv6

I'm doing some tests with my IPv6 through `curl` and `ping`. For some reasson, I can access IPv6 version of Google and some other websites, but I can't reach `npmjs.com` even `github.com`. See the examples:

**Error:**

```
[eduardo]:~/proj$ curl -v6 https://vulndetect.org/
*   Trying 2a05:d018:542:ed01:d2a2:a89a:c311:b79a:443...
* connect to 2a05:d018:542:ed01:d2a2:a89a:c311:b79a port 443 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to vulndetect.org port 443: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to vulndetect.org port 443: Timed out
```

**Success:**

```
[eduardo]:~/proj$ curl -v6 https:/google.com
*   Trying 2800:3f0:4001:825::200e:443...
* Connected to google.com (2800:3f0:4001:825::200e) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.google.com
*  start date: Nov  8 02:25:05 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 31 02:25:04 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "google.com" matched cert's "google.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services LLC; CN=GTS CA 1C3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x56303bd095a0)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: google.com
> user-agent: curl/7.74.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 301 
< location: https://www.google.com/
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< date: Tue, 14 Dec 2021 04:18:51 GMT
< expires: Thu, 13 Jan 2022 04:18:51 GMT
< cache-control: public, max-age=2592000
< server: gws
< content-length: 220
< x-xss-protection: 0
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
< 
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
* Connection #0 to host google.com left intact
```

Why is this happenning?

As stated on comments here, both working and not working websites use the same interface. The output of `traceroute` is:

```
[eduardo]:~/proj/DescicloBot/ai$ traceroute -6 vulndetect.org
traceroute to vulndetect.org (2a05:d018:542:ed01:d2a2:a89a:c311:b79a), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  2804:21ac:2d:ba01:da07:b6ff:feed:bf12 (2804:21ac:2d:ba01:da07:b6ff:feed:bf12)  1.466 ms  1.662 ms  1.631 ms
 2  as264566.portoalegre.rs.ix.br (2001:12f8:0:6::26:4566)  7.628 ms  7.599 ms  7.649 ms
 3  2804:41f8:f100:6::245 (2804:41f8:f100:6::245)  6.330 ms  6.298 ms  6.429 ms
 4  as3549.pae.w8telecom.com.br (2804:4c0:ffff:fd6b::1)  7.019 ms  6.836 ms  6.956 ms
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  ash-bb2-v6.ip.twelve99.net (2001:2034:1:74::1)  230.249 ms rest-bb1-v6.ip.twelve99.net (2001:2034:1:73::1)  225.400 ms ash-bb2-v6.ip.twelve99.net (2001:2034:1:74::1)  229.777 ms
 8  prs-bb2-v6.ip.twelve99.net (2001:2034:1:c1::1)  225.014 ms  224.981 ms prs-bb1-v6.ip.twelve99.net (2001:2034:1:be::1)  228.854 ms
 9  * * *
10  amazon-svc077640-lag003862.ip.twelve99-cust.net (2001:2000:3080:2a7::2)  272.221 ms  276.320 ms amazon-svc077642-lag003863.ip.twelve99-cust.net (2001:2000:3080:2a9::2)  272.064 ms
11  * * *
12  2a01:578:0:13::10 (2a01:578:0:13::10)  287.744 ms 2a01:578:0:13::e (2a01:578:0:13::e)  270.892 ms 2a01:578:0:13::f (2a01:578:0:13::f)  271.895 ms
13  2a01:578:0:8005::144 (2a01:578:0:8005::144)  239.728 ms 2a01:578:0:8005::142 (2a01:578:0:8005::142)  255.875 ms 2a01:578:0:8005::42 (2a01:578:0:8005::42)  238.658 ms
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6441:c06 (2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6441:c06)  262.467 ms 2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6441:d86 (2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6441:d86)  256.785 ms 2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6441:d8a (2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6441:d8a)  243.963 ms
18  2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:518 (2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:518)  249.560 ms 2620:107:4000:b1d0::f001:6c11 (2620:107:4000:b1d0::f001:6c11)  245.964 ms  246.392 ms
19  2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:788 (2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:788)  252.419 ms 2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:7e0 (2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:7e0)  249.711 ms 2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:6aa (2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:6aa)  249.937 ms
20  2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:1bcb (2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:1bcb)  248.753 ms 2a01:578:0:4009:8000:0:6442:a0d (2a01:578:0:4009:8000:0:6442:a0d)  247.744 ms 2a01:578:0:4009:8000:0:6442:b03 (2a01:578:0:4009:8000:0:6442:b03)  252.755 ms
21  2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:19df (2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:19df)  248.084 ms 2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:19c5 (2a01:578:0:4006:8000:0:6442:19c5)  248.817 ms 2a01:578:0:4009:8000:0:6442:1105 (2a01:578:0:4009:8000:0:6442:1105)  241.669 ms
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

Another not working website's traceroute:

```
[eduardo]:~/proj/DescicloBot/ai$ traceroute -6 2606:4700::6810:5c53 
traceroute to 2606:4700::6810:5c53 (2606:4700::6810:5c53), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  2804:21ac:2d:ba01:da07:b6ff:feed:bf12 (2804:21ac:2d:ba01:da07:b6ff:feed:bf12)  2.410 ms  2.357 ms  2.541 ms
 2  as264566.portoalegre.rs.ix.br (2001:12f8:0:6::26:4566)  7.153 ms  7.294 ms  7.259 ms
 3  2804:41f8:f100:6::245 (2804:41f8:f100:6::245)  6.498 ms  6.636 ms  6.602 ms
 4  2804:41f8:f800:1000::5 (2804:41f8:f800:1000::5)  23.435 ms  23.175 ms  22.837 ms
 5  as13335.saopaulo.sp.ix.br (2001:12f8::219:111)  37.315 ms  37.366 ms  37.332 ms
 6  2400:cb00:97:1024::ac44:1169 (2400:cb00:97:1024::ac44:1169)  23.845 ms 2400:cb00:97:1024::ac44:1229 (2400:cb00:97:1024::ac44:1229)  24.424 ms 2400:cb00:97:1024::ac44:1195 (2400:cb00:97:1024::ac44:1195)  24.889 ms
```

The last traced IP of both them are completely diferent as far I can see.

Reverse traceroute output:

```sh
traceroute to 2804:21ac:2d:ba01::3 (2804:21ac:2d:ba01::3), 50 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  * * * * *
 2  2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:1120 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:1120) [*]  195.557 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:1060 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:1060) [*]  195.543 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:1020 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:1020) [*]  195.471 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:12e0 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:12e0) [*]  195.459 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:1220 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:1220) [*]  195.504 ms
 3  2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:8b6 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:8b6) [*]  195.492 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:8a2 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:8a2) [*]  195.479 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:87c (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:87c) [*]  195.402 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:834 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:834) [*]  195.448 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:832 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:832) [*]  195.435 ms
 4  2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:a8c (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:a8c) [*]  195.423 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:b0a (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:b0a) [*]  1.314 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:b82 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:b82) [*]  199.132 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:bae (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:bae) [*]  2.826 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:b22 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:b22) [*]  199.134 ms
 5  2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:625 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:625) [*]  1.440 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:749 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:749) [*]  400.424 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:60b (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:60b) [*]  199.090 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:7ad (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:7ad) [*]  199.074 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:72d (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:72d) [*]  199.062 ms
 6  2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:48f (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:48f) [*]  199.004 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:47f (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:47f) [*]  198.991 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:44f (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:44f) [*]  4.478 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:46f (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:46f) [*]  9.556 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:45f (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6442:45f) [*]  4.432 ms
 7  2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:a01 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:a01) [*]  0.220 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:941 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:941) [*]  0.357 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:ae1 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:ae1) [*]  2.960 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:8a1 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:8a1) [*]  2.947 ms 2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:9c1 (2620:107:4000:4104:8000:0:6441:9c1) [*]  0.349 ms
 8  2620:107:4000:2::6f (2620:107:4000:2::6f) [*]  2.915 ms 2620:107:4000:2::70 (2620:107:4000:2::70) [*]  2.921 ms 2620:107:4000:2::86 (2620:107:4000:2::86) [*]  2.909 ms 2620:107:3000::16 (2620:107:3000::16) [AS16509]  2.878 ms 2620:107:4000:2::70 (2620:107:4000:2::70) [*]  2.762 ms
 9  * * * * *
10  2620:107:4000:2::76 (2620:107:4000:2::76) [*]  2.265 ms 2620:107:3000::b (2620:107:3000::b) [AS16509]  2.253 ms  2.228 ms  2.215 ms 2620:107:4000:2::78 (2620:107:4000:2::78) [*]  2.195 ms
11  2620:107:4000:8000::41 (2620:107:4000:8000::41) [*]  196.921 ms *  196.883 ms  196.869 ms 2620:107:4000:8000::43 (2620:107:4000:8000::43) [*]  196.848 ms
12  2620:107:4000:9018::c (2620:107:4000:9018::c) [*]  196.831 ms * 2620:107:4000:9011::9 (2620:107:4000:9011::9) [*]  9.146 ms 2620:107:4000:9011::b (2620:107:4000:9011::b) [*]  10.039 ms 2620:107:4000:9018::28 (2620:107:4000:9018::28) [*]  14.033 ms
13  * * * 2620:107:4000:9011::48 (2620:107:4000:9011::48) [*]  192.298 ms *
14  * 2620:107:4000:9018::46 (2620:107:4000:9018::46) [*]  10.145 ms * * *
15  2620:107:4000:9018::16 (2620:107:4000:9018::16) [*]  197.604 ms 2620:107:4000:9018::10 (2620:107:4000:9018::10) [*]  197.584 ms 2620:107:4000:9018::e (2620:107:4000:9018::e) [*]  197.560 ms 2620:107:4000:9018::14 (2620:107:4000:9018::14) [*]  197.548 ms 2620:107:4000:9018::13 (2620:107:4000:9018::13) [*]  197.589 ms
16  2001:1498:1::100:145 (2001:1498:1::100:145) [AS12956]  203.261 ms  203.267 ms 2620:107:4000:9019::26 (2620:107:4000:9019::26) [*]  197.540 ms 2001:1498:1::100:145 (2001:1498:1::100:145) [AS12956]  203.805 ms 240e:20:1800::db:b511 (240e:20:1800::db:b511) [AS4134]  397.512 ms
17  2804:1e48::4e2 (2804:1e48::4e2) [AS4809]  197.501 ms 2620:107:4000:9019::2f (2620:107:4000:9019::2f) [*]  197.741 ms 2001:1498:1::100:138 (2001:1498:1::100:138) [AS12956]  197.754 ms 2620:107:4000:9019::2b (2620:107:4000:9019::2b) [*]  197.694 ms 2804:1e48::4e2 (2804:1e48::4e2) [AS4809]  208.799 ms
18  2804:138:8fff:ffff:198:19:255:102 (2804:138:8fff:ffff:198:19:255:102) [AS11432]  210.635 ms  199.425 ms  199.652 ms  399.339 ms 2620:107:4000:9019::2e (2620:107:4000:9019::2e) [*]  199.426 ms
19  2620:107:4000:9019::46 (2620:107:4000:9019::46) [*]  199.413 ms 2804:138:8fff:deae::e2 (2804:138:8fff:deae::e2) [AS11432]  204.169 ms 2620:107:4000:9019::43 (2620:107:4000:9019::43) [*]  199.305 ms 2620:107:4000:9006::7b (2620:107:4000:9006::7b) [*]  199.363 ms 2804:138:8fff:deae::e2 (2804:138:8fff:deae::e2) [AS11432]  399.311 ms
20  2620:107:4000:9006::10 (2620:107:4000:9006::10) [*]  199.262 ms 2620:107:4000:9019::21 (2620:107:4000:9019::21) [*]  199.235 ms 2804:21ac:100::20a (2804:21ac:100::20a) [AS264566]  399.464 ms  399.444 ms  399.425 ms
21  2804:21ac:2d:ba01::3 (2804:21ac:2d:ba01::3) [AS264566]  399.408 ms  200.372 ms  401.845 ms * *
```

Comment: 1) Do you always get the same "connect timed out" error, or do the errors vary from site to site? 2) What ISP are you using for IPv6 access? 3) Does `ip route get <ipv6_address>` report the same interface for both working and not-working sites? 4) Does `traceroute` to them reveal anything common to the not-working sites?

Comment: Additional questions in case some of the errors are different: I) Are you using any tunnels (also including VPNs as well as PPPoE) to get the IPv6 access? II) Are you blocking ICMPv6 in any firewall? III) Does your network pass the http://icmpcheckv6.popcount.org/ test?

Comment: 1 - Everytime "Timed Out".
2 - Some called "Internet O Sul" (a brazillian startup).
3 - Posted on the question :)
4  - Gonna check
I - No, I'm over a PPPoE connection.
II - I don't know, I disabled DoS Protection on router.
III - It shows " All good! ICMP path MTU message was successfully delivered to you." and "All good! IP fragments were successfully delivered to your host.".

Comment: As a side note, PPPoE actually counts as a "tunnel" (it's fundamentally just a special kind of VPN connection to your ISP) – but it's not the source of the problem in your case. (All these additional questions were mostly just in case of timeouts after the "TLS Client Hello".) But if it always times out during the *initial connect*, then I feel like the problem is at your ISP's level. Traceroute might give better hints, but it's possible that there's nothing you can do to fix this.

Comment: @user1686 I don't know how to read traceroute's output. Are they DNS records? Can I just paste the results in the question (they are a bit large)?

Comment: Traceroute output is a list of routers' IP addresses (sometimes with their DNS names, sometimes without) – it shows the path that packets take from your network towards the specified destination. It's generally public information (the 1st hop is your home router, everything beyond that is addresses belonging your ISP or other ISPs). I'm not expecting it to show anything specifically useful, really, just something like "looks like traceroutes to all problematic sites hang at hop #4 so that definitely looks like a problem your ISP needs to resolve".

Comment: Okay, added it. They stop at a "* * *"

Comment: That looks like a normal one for vulndetect.org (which seems to be hosted on AWS)... looks like "reverse traceroute" websites (I tried https://mtr.sh) can reach your router back from that location just fine as well. Perhaps it's a problem with that specific website?

Comment: That's weird, because curl didn't worked for me (tried again)

Comment: gonna try, just a sec!

Comment: I looks like it reached my desktop

Comment: Don't use plain `traceroute`. If you are trying to see why it is failing with a certain TCP port, then try `traceroute -T -port=<destport> -f <starting ttl> <ADDR>`.

Comment: @Bib okay, I'll try